# AngularJs BootstrapUI Datepicker validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to validate the date of the datepicker and also limit the years (avoid 15-05-9999 for example).

This is my HTML code:

```
 <p class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="raisedOnDate" class="form-control" ng-model="date" ng-disabled="!viewSearchEvent.raisedOnActive"
                               datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="opened1" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-validator required />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event,'on')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    <p ng-show="!searchEventsForm.$valid" style="color: red;">Date is invalid!</p>
                    <p ng-show="searchEventsForm.$valid" style="color: green;">Date is valid!</p>
```

This is inside a `<form name="searchEventsForm" role="form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>`.

I made this directive to validate date type:

```
app.directive('dateValidator', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
        function validate(value) {

            var d = Date.parse(value);

            // it is a date
            if (isNaN(d)) { // d.valueOf() could also work
                ngModel.$setValidity('valid', false);
            } else {
                ngModel.$setValidity('valid', true);
            }
        }

        scope.$watch(function () {
            return ngModel.$viewValue;
        }, validate);
    }
};
```

});

But, I can enter dates like 25-05-999999999, and that is not the idea.

I managed to make it work so if it is a date it shows a message saying "Date is valid" and if not "date is invalid".

But I'm stuck there.

Any ideas on how can I put year limit and character limits and make it work?

I tried already with `max-date`, `max`, and others.

If you need more info just ask, I don't know if it is clear enough or well explained.
Thank you for the help! ;)

Comment: I have browsed Google and stackoverflow and didn't find anything that make this work. I'm still looking tho.

Comment: "angular bootstrap datepicker validation" gives me a lot of results, some of them pretty relevant.

Comment: Tried them, didn't work. I'm still trying them actually, modifying and so on.

Comment: try the angular-strap datepicker, that allows you to set a max-value and a min-value etc

Comment: I'm going to try it, I let you know! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

used this: `maxlength="10"` on the html to limit characters.

and this is to validate the date format is correct (avoid 1/1/1, or 11/06/201):

```
MyDirective.directive('dateValidator', function() {
     return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
             function validate(value) {
                 if (value !== undefined && value != null) {
                     ngModel.$setValidity('badDate', true);
                     if (value instanceof Date) {
                         var d = Date.parse(value);
                         // it is a date
                         if (isNaN(d)) {
                             ngModel.$setValidity('badDate', false);
                         }
                     } else {
                         var myPattern = new RegExp(/^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$/);
                         if (value !='' && !myPattern.test(value)) {
                             ngModel.$setValidity('badDate', false);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

             scope.$watch(function () {
                 return ngModel.$viewValue;
             }, validate);
         }
     };
});
```

Still didn't manage to fix a min date and max date, but is not urgent.
Hope it can help people in future issues.

Comment: This is something easier to do with build in, angular directives

Answer (score 7):

Why dont you use ng-pattern?? instead of making a new directive.

Read more about it here [NG-PATTERN DOCS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

```
 ng-pattern="/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/"
```

Take a look at this fiddle with a better solution

[validate datepicker using ng-pattern](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/j4ddkm98/51/)

Comment: Nice. I will give you a +1. The piece of work is way finished. But I had a look to ng-pattern and offers a good way to approach the issue. Thanks.

Comment: ng-pattern does not work with datepicker because the ngModel has been changed into date object instead of string

Comment: Anyone still reading this outdated thread should know that the datepicker component now has built-in validation. View the docs, keep an eye out for the "formats" variable

Answer (score -1):

Your solution uses 'scope.$watch' to do what ngModel's '$parsers' and '$formatters' was built to do. Take a look here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: there is no ngModel.$parse

Comment: whoa, you are correct ... edited to referrence the correct methods.